# How to configure when compiling Uboot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu, u-boot, trustzone

I followed the intructions in [This project](https://github.com/ckuethe/usbarmory/wiki/QEMU-Virtual-Armory) and got stuck in the compilation of Uboot.
I have completely no idea how to make the following configurations
    `# add CONFIG_RSA, CONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE, CONFIG_CMD_EXT2
    # change the environment config to point to MMC
    # fix compiled-in config
    # maybe disable environment manipulation?
    # maybe change TEXT_BASE, or use mkimage to allow loading by "qemu -bios"?`

How to "add CONFIG_RSA, CONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE, CONFIG_CMD_EXT2" and "change the environment config to point to MMC"? What is **environment config**? I find nothing in the *include/configs/vexpress_common.h*, should I add it myself? If so, what is the syntax.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe I can give you a little help.
Yes, you need to add these defines yourself.
Add these to vexpress_common.h:

```
#define CONFIG_RSA
#define CONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE
#define CONFIG_CMD_EXT2
```

I think they meant to choose a media to store the environment parameters to, something like:

```
#define CONFIG_ENV_IN_MMC
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I contact the author today and here is his reply:"This page is mostly notes of experimental approaches, rather than a fully working configuration. I also haven't had any success in getting RSA checking to work - please let me know if you get it to work." So sad:(